# How to extract data out of an element querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am passing an array of data from a jQuery script to an html element and trying to extract the data out of the element for use in a regular javaScript script. In the console I see the data being passed. Using the querySelector I can get the whole construct, but I cannot get the array back out of the construct.

The data looks like this:

```
[{"zone":"alessandros_office","value":76},
{"zone":"it_closet","value":72},
{"zone":"kitchen","value":79},
{"zone":"main_conference_room","value":152},
{"zone":"neils_office","value":58},
{"zone":"training_room","value":29}]
```

This is the html element that receives the data:

```
<div id="bubbleData" data-type="text" data-visitors=""></div>
```

This is the jQuery function that passes the data to the div after an AJAX call to get it.

```
this.Update = function (data) {
                if (_.isUndefined(data) || _.isNull(data)) {
                    data = {};
                }

                console.log('Bubble js data: ', data);

                this.BubbleChart.Update(data);
              //$('#bubbleData').attr('data-visitors', data);
            };
```

In the javascript script I extract the data and display it in a console.log with this:

```
const bubble = document.querySelector('[data-visitors]');
var data = bubble.dataset;
console.log('Visitor Data: ', data);
```

And in the console I see this:

```
Visitor Data: 
    DOMStringMap {id: 'visit', visitors: ''}
         id: "visit"
         visitors: "[{\"zone\":\"alessandros_office\",\"value\":76},{\"zone\":\"it_closet\",\"value\":72},{\"zone\":\"kitchen\",\"value\":79},{\"zone\":\"main_conference_room\",\"value\":152},{\"zone\":\"neils_office\",\"value\":58},{\"zone\":\"training_room\",\"value\":29}]"
```

According to mdm web docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes, I should be able to access the 'visitors' data with 'bubble.dataset.visitors', but a console.log of that turns up empty. How do I extract the visitors data?

Answer (score 1):

See [the manual for `data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

You can't use standard DOM APIs to read data stored using jQuery's `data`. It stores it internally to jQuery, not in the DOM.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me, but I'm still not getting the data. I changed the jQuery to '$('div #bubbleData').attr('data-visitors', data);' and on the other end, I changed to 'var data = document.querySelector('[data-visitors]');'. Still no joy

Comment: Does `div #bubbleData` match anything in your document? You have a descendant combinator in there, but your HTML snippet doesn't have the ancestor element.

Comment: No, it is unique

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense as an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Misunderstood your question - this is the element: <div id="bubbleData" data-id="visit" data-visitors=""></div>

Comment: Yes, you said that already. What about the ancestor you have in the selector?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247855/discussion-between-davidn-and-quentin).

Comment: Any idea why I'm still not getting the passed data in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is just a misunderstanding between JSON and a Javascript Object.

This code illustrates the differences.

```js
data = [{"zone":"alessandros_office","value":76},
{"zone":"it_closet","value":72},
{"zone":"kitchen","value":79},
{"zone":"main_conference_room","value":152},
{"zone":"neils_office","value":58},
{"zone":"training_room","value":29}];

function fnGetData(){

$('#bubbleData').data('visitors',JSON.stringify(data));
var objData = $('#bubbleData').data('visitors');
var json = $.parseJSON(objData);
var strData = JSON.stringify(objData);
console.log(strData);
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(strData);
console.log(jsonData);
console.log(json[2].zone);  



// Show the string data the way you are currently seeing it.
console.log(JSON.stringify(objData));
console.log(json[2].zone);  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="fnGetData()">getdata</button>

<div id="bubbleData" data-visitors=""></div>
```

Comment: Thank you jeffld, the problem is that I am trying to extract the data in a d3 javascript script. Also the data is already a string.

Comment: The $.parseJSON(strData) will get the string in the JSON format.  I edited the code to show what happens.

Comment: The problem is that the script that picks up the data is not jQuery. I'm fairly familiar with jQuery, but I don't know how to pass data FROM a jQuery script to an HTML DOM element and then pick it up with vanilla javascript in the d3 code.